# Silverlight 4 how to format a binded decimal value

Tags: c#, silverlight, bind, cultureinfo

Hey, sorry for my bad english...

I have a very simple textbox on my sl4 app, like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource Valor}, Path=ValorReal, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, StringFormat=\{0:c\}, NotifyOnValidationError=True}" />
```

and a class like:

```
public class Valor: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    double _valorReal;
    public double ValorReal
    {
        get
        {
            return _valorReal;
        }
        set
        {
            _valorReal = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ValorReal");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
}
```

I live in Brazil, so here the decimal separator is "," and the grouping digit is ".", so
$1.000,50 is one thousand dollars and fifty cents.

But using the sample above, if i digit 1000,50 on the textbox, after i exit the field it turns to $100,050.00. How do i get the correct settings?

The **CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator** have the right values but silverlight is ignoring them on my binding :(

I tried to put
`System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pt-BR");`
there but, nothing happen...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to include the {0:} in the format string.

```
{Binding Source={StaticResource Valor}, Path=ValorReal, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, StringFormat=c, NotifyOnValidationError=True}
```

Comment: excuse me but what does the "c" in StringFormat=c means?

Comment: Take a look at the [Standard Numeric Formatting from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx).
"C" is for currency.

Comment: "C" or "c"
Currency
Result: A currency value.
Supported by: All numeric types.
Precision specifier: Number of decimal digits.
Default precision specifier: Defined by System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.
More information: The Currency ("C") Format Specifier.
123.456 ("C", en-US) -> $123.46
123.456 ("C", fr-FR) -> 123,46 €
123.456 ("C", ja-JP) -> ¥123
-123.456 ("C3", en-US) -> ($123.456)
-123.456 ("C3", fr-FR) -> -123,456 €
-123.456 ("C3", ja-JP) -> -¥123.456